# Javascript Code giving error on chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript, web-services, firefox, google-chrome, soap

I have used below lines in my code for consuming web services using javascript

```
var ns = (wsdl.documentElement.attributes["targetNamespace"] + "" == "undefined") ? wsdl.documentElement.attributes.getNamedItem("targetNamespace").nodeValue : wsdl.documentElement.attributes["targetNamespace"].value;
```

the above javascript code is running fine on IE and safari but on chrome and firefox it is throwing error on console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.50.141:4323/HelloWorld.asmx?wsdl. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null
```

Please Help

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` tells the reason.

Comment: Where are you running the code? Is it indeed not on `http://192.168.50.141:4323/`?

Answer (score 0):

If you run chrome with the command line

like

```
chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

This is what i use  when developing